# Can my app access the Notes (Apple app) folder in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm writing an app that handles PDF files, and I want it to take the notes created by the Notes app then convert them to PDF then the app can work on that.

Is it possible for my app to access that folder containing the notes without jailbreaking the device?

(I would ask the same with the iBooks app file as well).

Comment: I am trying to do this same thing. I mean the part about accessing the contents of a Note in the Notes app in an iOS device. Have you been able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All applications are sandboxed so you can not access the Users notes that they created in the Notes Application. Apple provides no SDK methods which you can use without Jailbreaking and private methods.

A potential (but cumbersome) solution could be that Notes could be synced to a Users IMAP account. You could see if you could communicate with the IMAP Server by asking for the Login Credentials and then grabbing the Notes.

Comment: well thank you very much for the fast reply. I'll have to redirect the app in another way then.

Comment: Hi Suhail, do you know if it's the same or not for iBooks which is not a pre-installed app? Thanks very much.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Even more so because iBooks is not preinstalled. The iBooks app and it's books are sandboxed just like the Notes Application and the same with your application so you can not access the data between Applications

Comment: No worries :). Please do accept the answer if you think it's helpful and answers the question in the best possible way.

Comment: +1 @SuhailPatel can you plz tell me is it possible to add notes from native app to the apples ios notes?

Comment: @Dhara I have seen third party apps that does that. The do it as part of a "Share" feature that Apple uses as a standard. There may be already a framework or a way that Apple gives developers who want to put a Share feature in their app.

Comment: @SuhailPatel When the user signs into an iOS device with an Apple ID, is he/she signing into what you call a "Users IMAP" account. I am trying to figure out if I my app could access a Note in the Notes app the way you describe using the account the user signs into the iOS device with.