# Notes List from Notes app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can my app access the Notes (Apple app) folder in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428458/can-my-app-access-the-notes-apple-app-folder-in-ios)

Can we get list of notes from the iOS Notes app? I want to get list of notes added by user in iphone Notes app.

Comment: [no, you can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428458/can-my-app-access-the-notes-apple-app-folder-in-ios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428483/1648976

Tells:

All applications are sandboxed so you can not access the Users notes that they created in the Notes Application. Apple provides no SDK methods which you can use without Jailbreaking and private methods.

A potential (but cumbersome) solution could be that Notes could be synced to a Users IMAP account. You could see if you could communicate with the IMAP Server by asking for the Login Credentials and then grabbing the Notes.

Comment: You may as well flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thats's kind of weird, because of the upvote i just got i recieved the privilege to do so. weird...